# CSS3PIE Background Fading Background Color

Tags: debugging, transparency, background-color, css3pie

I have configured css3pie on my drupal website http://tinyurl.com/cyfxly4 for corner radius on ie 8 and 7 it works fine but its fading the background color. I have not define any transparency command any where.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what background is being faded? It looks identical in IE8 as it does in Firefox for me: http://cl.ly/2T2p2L3T1p1n1S3p2p1N

Comment: Its resolved now, actually side bar and banner divs were overlap by the container div which had a 50% transparent image on it.

Answer (score 0):

> actually side bar and banner divs were overlap by the container div which had a 50% transparent image on it